# Difference in thread behaviour while accessing variable

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm, thread-safety, volatile

I was going through the tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SC2jXxOPe5E to understand how volatile variable works and came across a strange behavior.

For the following code snippet

```
public class VolatileDemo {
    static boolean running = false;
    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!running) {
                }
                System.out.print("Started");
                while (running) {
                }
                System.out.print("Stopped");
            }
        });
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        running = true;
        System.out.print("Starting ");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        running = false;
        System.out.print("Stopping");
    }
}
```

The output is : Starting Stopping (which is understandable by video)

But for the following code snippet

```
public class VolatileDemo {
    static boolean running = false;
    public static void main(String a[]) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!running) {
                    System.out.print("Flag " + running);
                }
                System.out.print(" Started");
                while (running) {
                    System.out.print(" Flag " + running);
                }
                System.out.print(" Stopped");
            }
        });
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        running = true;
        System.out.print(" Starting");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        running = false;
        System.out.print(" Stopping");
    }
}
```

The output is Flag: false Starting Started Flag: true Stopping Stopped(ignore the output)

My concern here is why the thread was able to read the updated value of '*running*' in case 2?

Edit: The difference between the two snippets is the addition below statement in later case

```
System.out.print("Flag " + running);
```

Comment: Your code snippets seem the same. Could you highlight the differences?

Comment: You have your logic wrong. Making a variable volatile allows bringing memory visibility guarantees, and make code thread-safe. That doesn't mean that not using volatile guarantees memory invisibility. Just like: looking both sides before crossing the road makes sure you won't get hit by a car. That doesn't mean that you're guaranteed to get hit by a car if you don't look before crossing. It's unsafe to do so, but you're not guaranteed to have an accident.

Comment: @JBNizet Great analogy

Answer (score 0):

I think it's important to understand what the purpose of volatile is.

On a multi-processor system with multiple levels of cache an update to a variable can take some time to reach main memory and hence other threads depending on latency and the hardware design. The code basically is supposed to demo this happening, the change to the running variable is changed and the output should show some delay between when it was changed and when the thread actually starts. Adding the volatile keyword should reduce this delay as it forces the write through to main memory to happen immediately instead of when the cache decides to do it.

Please note that volatile doesn't make code thread safe, it just tells the JVM that the variable needs to be written directly to main memory bypassing any delayed writing scheme the caching hardware might otherwise do. It also means that the variable is read from main memory so that stale data is not used. It is for reducing the latency between a variable being updated in one thread and seen to be updated in another. This isn't something you'll need often, and should use sparingly as bypassing the cache will have performance ramifications for your code.

When you've added extra instructions to the code of the thread you've effectively significantly reduced the rate at which it can poll the running variable. I'd say it's likely that the time between running being changed and being updated in main memory is very small, much quicker than the time it takes to output on the console (which takes longer than you'd think). So it is very likely that you won't see what you expect except on the rare occasion that the boolean evaluation in the while loop happens at the exact correct moment.

Unlike deadlock, this particular property of multi-processing is quite hard to demonstrate on a single machine. It's much more likely to happen on a NUMA system architecture (or a cluster) where the cache to memory update latency can be much larger. On a single system the time between a variable being updated in cache and written to main memory is very small.